# TPL's Parallel.For creates and destroys threads too much. How do I keep the number of threads constant?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have some code written to use Parallel.For with thread local variables. It's basically a summation of a large array, but the elements of the array are calculated explicitly in the for loop at the same time they are being summed.

The problem I'm having is that my thread-local variables are very, very heavy objects. It's not uncommon for them to take up 200 mb of memory. I noticed my program's memory usage would spike to 2 gb, then the GC would drop it back down to 200 mb and up and down it went, which indicated a lot of temporaries were being allocated. Since I need several thread-local variables, I've wrapped them in a struct object. This allowed me to add a Console.WriteLine in the constructor and I saw a lot of my objects being created whereas I only expected one construction per core on my machine. How can I force it to create exactly (numberOfCores) threads and keep only those around until the end?

I added

```
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2;
```

which helped only slightly. I still get too many struct constructions. It looks like there is something I can do with options.TaskScheduler, but I can't seem to understand what the extent of its power is. It looks like I can roll my own, which is almost scary. I don't want to do that if possible.

Here is the relevant section of code in my program.

```
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2;

Parallel.For<ThreadLocalData>(0, m, options,
    // Thread local variable initialization
    () => new ThreadLocalData(new DenseMatrix(r * r, r * r, 0),
                              new DenseMatrix(r * r, r * r, 0),
                              new DenseMatrix(r, r, 0)),
    // Per-thread routine
    (row, loop, threadLocalData) =>
    {
        threadLocalData.kronProductRight.Clear();
        for (int column = 0; column < n; ++column)
        {
            if ((int)E[row, column] == 1)
                threadLocalData.kronProductRight.Add(Yblocks[column], threadLocalData.kronProductRight);
        }
        MathNetAdditions.KroneckerProduct(Xblocks[row], threadLocalData.kronProductRight, threadLocalData.kronProduct);
        threadLocalData.subtotal.Add(threadLocalData.kronProduct, threadLocalData.subtotal);
        return threadLocalData;
    },
    (threadLocalData) =>
    {
        lock (mutex)
        A.Add(threadLocalData.subtotal, A);
    }
);
```

Comment: You assume incorrectly that the oscillating memory usage implies creation and destruction of threads.  A memory profile like that can occur even in single-threaded applciations.  It's possible that some method is creating tons of short-lived objects and abandoning them to the garbage collector (`KroneckerProduct`, perhaps?).  If any of your types is an array of reference types, this is very likely.  To give a more specific answer, it would help to know the definition of `DenseMatrix`, of the `Clear` method, the declaration (or at least the type) of `E`, and the type of `Xblocks` and `Yblocks`

Comment: I have determined that those aren't the culprits. I can comment out everything inside the loop and I'll still get the same memory behavior. No memory is allocated within the loop.

Comment: some of the things I asked about are outside the loop, namely the Clear and KroneckerProduct methods.  Does Clear perhaps clear the data by creating new arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/10/21/10079121.aspx Especially the parts about Parallel.For having a performance issue when the initialize delegate is expensive.

From looking at the code above its hard to tell, but it looks like you should be able to separate the computational/data parts of your ThreadLocalData from the stateful/mutating aspects of it? Ideally, you would pass a reference to an immutable version of ThreadLocalData to whatever is crunching your numbers.  That way, no matter what, you're just dealing with one instance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gotten into the thick of your question (and it seems you are asking the wrong question as phoog pointed out), but to answer your specific question:

> How can I force it to create exactly (numberOfCores) threads and keep
>   only those around until the end?

You have a scheduler that does exactly this:

http://blog.abodit.com/2010/11/task-parallel-library-a-scheduler-with-priority-apartment-state-and-maximum-degree-of-parallelism/

Comment: That looked very promising and I tried it. I even read the code and can't see how it could possibly create more than 2 threads, but I'm watching my task manager and I get the same memory problems and I can see the number of threads continue to go up as time goes on. The computation takes on the order of 2 minutes and 2 threads are created roughly every 5 seconds. I added TaskScheduler scheduler = new Utility.ConstantThreadScheduler(2); options.TaskScheduler = scheduler; to my code. Is that right?

Comment: In fact, the default scheduler's behavior didn't include increasing the number of threads visible in the task manager. They stayed constant.

Comment: Assuming you only created one instance of the scheduler, the other threads are definitely brought up someplace else. If you can't figure it out from static analysis of the code, you should consider profiling. I'm not sure, but VS has a concurrency profiler that may be of use in this regard.